# Getting Latest Post on top (Reverse Chronological Order)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following but my posts are still in Chronological Order (Oldest to New). My target is to have latest post on the top. (Newest to Old)

```
$catquery = new WP_Query( array (
    'cat'=>'27', 
    'post_type'=>'news', 
    'orderby' => "post_date", 
    'order' => "DESC" ) 
);

while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();

<p class="date"> <?php the_date(); ?> </p>

<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

<p> <?php the_content('Read More', FALSE); ?>
```

I have also tried `orderby' => "date"` but no luck. How to solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ASC`?

Comment: @elclanrs as per my knowledge "The ASC option specifies an index maintained in ascending order; this is the default order. The DESC option can specify an index that is maintained in descending order" 

My target is to have latest post on the top and so on .. 

Thank You for your Response

Comment: try `'orderby' => "date"`

Comment: @Kamil I tried the same as well but no luck

Comment: you have a use custom post type news?

Comment: @ Ravi Yes news is post type wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=news this is the url of new news post.

Comment: where to add a category to generate url in (taxonomy=bgmp-category)
xxx/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=bgmp-category&post_type=bgmp
bgmp-category to relace news_category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close, but there are a few problems.

1. `'cat'` expects an int not a string so you need `'cat'=>27,`
2. Instead of `post_date` you need `date`
3. I'm not sure which order you need so try `ASC` if `DESC` doesn't work.

Here's the new query:

```
$catquery = new WP_Query(array (
  'cat'       => 27, 
  'post_type' => 'news', 
  'orderby'   => 'date', 
  'order'     => 'DESC'
));
```

- order (string) - Designates the ascending or descending order of the 'orderby' parameter. **Defaults to 'DESC'.**

  - 'ASC' - ascending order from lowest to highest values (1, 2, 3; a, b, c).
  - 'DESC' - descending order from highest to lowest values (3, 2, 1; c, b, a).

Here's a reference: [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: I have already tried this, you can see last line of my question

I have also tried orderby' => "date" but no luck. 

Thank You @graham

Comment: @Shiva are you sure `news` is a post type and not a category or tag? I know it's possible to have custom post types, but I'm just checking

Comment: Yes news is post type `wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=news` this is the url of new news item.

Comment: Hold on you want old -> new, you need `ASC`. I misread your question. I've updated my answer

Comment: My target is to have latest post on the top. New ---- > Old 

My question title is `Getting Latest Post on top (Reverse Chronological Order)`

Even after that I tried `ASC` But still no luck

Thank you

Comment: And in your question you have `but my posts are still in Chronological Order (newest to old)` so it's not exactly clear. If the posts are coming out in the wrong order, either `ASC` or `DESC` will work.

Comment: Yes these was confusion in my question so I have updated it now , Sorry for your trouble , So far using both way My post are still in old -- > new order , I Need them to be new --- > old

Comment: @Shiva, why can't you just reverse the array then? all the posts are in correct, but ascending order? try `array_reverse()` on post array and see what are you getting, maybe sort column name is wrong.

Comment: @Shiva I just saw that `cat` is being set to a string instead of an int, see my updated answer.

Comment: @GrahamWalters thank You for your great effort, but even by making `cat` as `int` did not helped me.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     your post is custom post type so use this argument:'
> ```

```
    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(

                'taxonomy' => 'news_category',

                'field' => 'id',

                'terms' => '27'

            )
        ),
        'post_type'=>'news',
        'order_by'=>'date',
        'order'=>'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=>-1
);
    query_posts($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>
    <li>
        <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li> 
<?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Thank You @ravi but unfortunately this `'tax_query'`is not able to fetch the posts. 

Am I missing any specific ID or line.. 

No post is being display after using this query.

Comment: Thank You for your effort `http://xxxxxx/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID=27&post_type=news`

I have put `'taxonomy' => 'category'` Now post are being display on the page but **new post --- > old old** order is not there.

Comment: post per page in change you display no of post and add after endwhile <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>